# How to get list of class properties into string using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following class:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName = string.Empty;
        public string LastName = string.Empty;
    }
```

and list of that class:

```
List<Person> listOfPeople = new List<Person>();
```

How do I get list FirstNames into string or string list variable from listOfPeople without using foreach and looping through it?
I want to get something like:

```
string firstNames= "Bob, Jack, Bill";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `Select` combined with `string.Join` will give you what you want.

```
string firstNames = string.Join(", ", listOfPeople.Select(p=>p.FirstName));
```

Depending on what version of .Net you are using you might also need to add a `ToArray` after the `Select` as the overload of `string.Join` that takes a `IEnumerable<string>` was not added until .Net 4.

On a side note consider turning your public fields into properties.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        FirstName = string.Empty;
        LastName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq Aggregate function to achieve this

```
listOfPeople.Select(person => person.FirstName).Aggregate((i, j) => i + ", " + j);
```

Comment: Note this is the equivalent of doing [string concatenation in a loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182272%28VS.80%29.aspx).